# android show dialog from menu options doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout

```
   //called when hardware button "Menu" clicked
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

and then this

```
@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_options:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, EditPreferences.class));   
                break;
        case R.id.menu_about:
             Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//NO TITLE :)
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.menu_about);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);
                dialog.show();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

//return true;
//return false;
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
```

using debug i see i enter the **switch case R.id.menu_about**, but **dialog.show() doesn't do anything**

the dialog just won't show, i tried using standart AlertDialog too, no luck either

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so post it please.

Comment: no error, just the menu bar that disappears

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to change:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
```

to

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
```

Comment: Omg, I just saw that. I can't believe that I missed it. @Max, Yes a dialog (view in general) CANNOT be created using the application context.

Comment: Thank you, i always thought getApplicationContext() and this are the same thing, what is the difference beetween these two ? :)

Comment: It's used to keep global state of application: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html